# How to add space for Label text dynamically in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi all i am trying to add an image dynamically to a `Label` as follows which works fine, but i would like to add a `space` after the image and i would like to write mt required text i tried as follows but i am unable to find space between image and text

```
Label1.Text = "<img src='Images/warning (1).png' />Select atleast one?";
```

I need space(tab space) after the image

My present one is as follows

[image]

Comment: Eww. Setting an img tag in Label.Text? There has to be a better way! CSS? Or an asp:Image control where you toggle the Visible flag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `&nbsp;` (space).

```
Label1.Text = "<img src='Images/warning (1).png' />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Select atleast one?";
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could try

```
Label1.Text = "<img src='Images/warning (1).png' />nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;Select atleast one?";
```

or you coud use two different controls, one for the image and one for the text, and use a table to make them "look pretty"

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also use css like

```
img{ margin-right:5px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Label1.Text = "<img src='Images/warning (1).png' />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Select atleast one?";
```