# &nbsp; in asp.net server side code?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code :

```
string s = "royi";
string val = "5";
```

I also have a `label` `<asp:Label ..../>`

I want to create `s+" "+val`

but I want That the `" "` will be `&nbsp;`

How can I do it in *server* side  ?

Doing this is showing me the `&nbsp` as text. ( ofcourse since we're dealing with myLabel.*Text* which holds a text)

I've also tried :

```
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(s + "&nbsp;" + val);
```

any help ?

Comment: Can you use `asp:Literal` control instead?

Comment: It seems to work for [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758392/how-to-add-space-for-label-text-dynamically-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`&nbsp;` is a *different* character than space - it is Unicode code point `00A0`. See on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).

If you use that character, you should be getting a non breaking space.

Comment: ps , I know that nbsp is different thats why i asked its equivalent in the server side. ( as opposed to do it in the aspx...) ....:)