# How does html decoding work?

Tags: c#

In my app I compare strings. I have strings that look the same but some of them contain white space, and other contain nbsp, so when I compare them I get that they are different. However, they represent the same entity so I have issues when I compare them. That's why I want to decode the strings I compare. That way nbsp will be converted to space in both of the strings and they will be treated as equal when I do the comparison. So here's what I do:

```
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(string1)[0]
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(string2)[0]
```

But I still get that string1[0] has ascii code of 160, and string2[0] has ascii code of 32.

Obviously I am not understanding the concept. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The non-breaking space and whitespace are different characters. They are not equal. See [`Char.IsWhiteSpace(Char)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: "they represent the same entity" based on what logic? Define your *sameness*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [&nbsp; in asp.net server side code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196266/nbsp-in-asp-net-server-side-code)

Comment: @Andrey For example I have list of names like "some restaurant", and I need to search in db for these names. So if I find "some restaurant" record in my db, it's the same one.

Comment: ascii 160 is not ascii, as ascii has only 128 7-bit characters. The encoding is important here: utf-8, or some other 8-bit encoding. Before comparing strings, you must figure out the encoding.

Comment: @petko_stankoski it is not same if it has different characters (whether they are printable of not). So you need to normalize your strings before putting them into db

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare two different characters, no matter how resembling they might seem to you.

The fact that they have different character codes is enough to make the comparison fail. The easiest thing to do is replace the non-breaking space by a regular space and then compare them.

```
bool c = html.Replace('\u00A0', ' ').Equals(regular);
```

Comment: No, you are just decoding the HTML and return a character with code 160.